# Getting blank screen and Error - SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Expected '(' while loading React app URL using WebView control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uwp, vite, uwp-xaml

We have build React SPA built using Vite, Typescript, and Tailwindcss.
Now we are facing problem while loading the above hosted react app URL inside WebView of UWP solution. The same URL getting loaded using Webview2 controller which comes with latest target version of UWP(Build 19041). But in our case, we don't want to upgrade the version so need to achieve the same using current UWP version(Build 14393). Any help on this will be appreciated.
[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- needed for outdated peer-dependencies that use global variable -->
    <script>
       if (globalThis === undefined) {
        var globalThis = window;
      }
       window.global = globalThis
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>` You should be transpiling the Typescript to JavaScript and referencing that instead.

Comment: @phuzi can you please elaborate, not understood. How to reference?

Comment: The browser cannot natively understand .ts/.tsx/.jsx, any of these will need converting to plain JavaScript using something like babel, webpack etc. before the browser will be able to consume it.